# Uneditable QListView

Tags: static, locking, pyqt, edit, qlistview

I have a QListView displaying a list of items but I don't want the items to be edited (Currently a double click on the item allows you to edit them).

This is my Code:

```
self.listView = QListView()
self.model = QStringListModel([ "item1" , "item2" , "item3" ])
self.listView.setModel( self.model )

self.layout = QGridLayout()  
self.layout.addWidget(self.listView, 0 , 0 )
self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Adding the line:

```
self.listView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

should fix things for you.

`QListView` inherits `QAbstractItemView` which has the method [`setEditTriggers()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setEditTriggers). Other [possible values](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum) for `setEditTriggers` are available in the docs.

Comment: This is more of a hack as it will still be editable, just not through this particular view.

Comment: listView.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers); for C++ qt

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses. I ended up going with a `QListWidget` instead as it is not editable by default.

Though I also found if you give the `QListView` a mouse Double clicked event and set it to do something other than edit the `QListView`, it overrides the edit function so that works too.

Comment: Using QListWidget is a great solution

Answer (score 0):

`QStringListModel` is by definition editable. You should subclass and provide the appropriate [flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum)

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Archived link from 2011 here: https://web.archive.org/web/20110807124820/http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags

Answer (score 0):

If `model` will be attached to multiple views and you don't want it to be editable by any of them, you can subclass `QStringListModel` and override `flags()`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class UneditableStringListModel(QStringListModel):

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsSelectable & Qt.ItemIsEnabled


listView = QListView()
model = UneditableStringListModel([ "item1" , "item2" , "item3" ])
listView.setModel(model)
```

Now the user will not be able to edit `model` from any view.